# How do I upload data to a server with valid SSL certificate using a client vb.net program?

Tags: vb.net, ssl, https, vb.net-2010

I am working on a program and uploads a shipping manifest to a the shippers website. When I try to upload, I get a nondescript error back from their server, and when checking with the shipper, they tell me that "there is an issue with the SSL" I am using.

I've spent quite a bit of time piecing together code that, from what I seem to understand, is supposed to work, but I'm not making any progress. As far as I know everything else is fine with the upload, but there is a problem with my SSL certificate

If I understand what this code is supposed to do correctly, I should get a certificate from the shippers website, which allows certification to my program for a space of time during which I can upload the data. I'm really not sure that this is what my code is doing at all, but the only code examples I have seen show it something like this.

Here's my code with the URLs changed:

```
    'This references a custom class that compiles the manifest I'm going to upload
    Dim StringToUpload As String = Compile_Manifest(MyDate, UseTestDB)

    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    webClient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

    'From what I understand, 
    'this is supposed to set up properties used in next section of code
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = _
        AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications

    'I can see that this reaches the server, 
    'but I don't know how it relates to the next section of code 
    'that actually uploads the manifest
    Dim ServerRequest As System.Net.WebRequest = _
        System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://www.certify.some-shippper.com:443/somefolder")
    Dim ServerResponse As System.Net.WebResponse
    ServerResponse = ServerRequest.GetResponse()
    ServerResponse.Close()

    'This code works for the upload of the manifest, 
    'and it seems the above code is unrelated and does not use a SSL certificate.
    'When this code runs I get the same error back from the shippers server, 
    'indicating an issue with my SSL, with or without the two sections of code above.
    Dim StrResult As String = ""
    Dim WrappedString As String = TransmitPLD.WrapPldFile(StringToUpload)
    'This references a custom class that wraps the data to upload 
    'in information from the shipper.
    Dim ByesToUpload As Byte() = _
        System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncodeToBytes(WrappedString, _
                                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII)
    Dim Result As Byte() = _
        webClient.UploadData("https://www.certify.some-shippper.com:443/somefolder", _
                             ByesToUpload)

    StrResult = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Result, _
                        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII)

    MessageBox.Show(StrResult)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I went about it the wrong way. I needed to upload my data through System.Net.WebRequest and it takes care of the certificates for me. Not implementing all the parts of the code I needed, it didn't handle the retrieval of the shipper's certificate.

In case anyone else gets confused about the matter like I did, here's my working code for anyone to see, adapt and use. My resource for fixing the code (and by that I mean starting from scratch) was the MSDN page for the WebRequest class, and it has code examples much the same as what I have below in C++, C#, and VB.NET and [here is the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.method%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

First there are some global variables that need to be set and class that needs to be created for to store the upload response:

```
' This is set in the function that Upload function 
'  and uploads the data in the ReadCallback sub
Private Shared WrappedString As String
' This is used to wait for the callback in the Upload function
Private Shared allDone As New Threading.ManualResetEvent(False)

Friend Class RequestState
    ' This class stores the request state of the request. 
    Public request As Net.WebRequest

    Public Sub New()
        request = Nothing
    End Sub ' New 
End Class ' RequestState
```

Then there is a sub needed for the upload part web request which will be called further below in the upload function:

```
Private Shared Sub ReadCallback(asynchronousResult As IAsyncResult)
    Try
        Dim myRequestState As RequestState = CType(asynchronousResult.AsyncState, RequestState)
        Dim myWebRequest As Net.WebRequest = myRequestState.request
        ' End the request. 
        Dim streamResponse As IO.Stream = myWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult)
        ' Convert  the string into a byte array. 
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(WrappedString)
        ' Write the data to the stream.
        streamResponse.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        streamResponse.Close()
        ' Allow the main thread to resume.
        allDone.Set()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Error in " & Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name.ToString & " **" & ex.Message, ex)
    End Try
End Sub ' ReadCallback
```

Finally, this is the function that should be called to upload the data, which uses all the code above:

```
Public Shared Function Upload(ByVal MyDate As Date) As String

    Dim StrResult As String = ""
    UploadSucess = False

    Try

        ' This is my code that builds the manifest that I want to upload
        Dim StringToUpload As String = Compile_PLD200(MyDate)
        WrappedString = TransmitPLD.WrapPldFile(StringToUpload)

        Dim myWebRequest As Net.WebRequest
        myWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create("https://www.some.website.com:443/someplace")

        ' Create an instance of the RequestState and assign 
        '  myWebRequest to it's request field.
        Dim myRequestState As New RequestState()
        myRequestState.request = myWebRequest
        myWebRequest.ContentType = "multipart/mixed; boundary=BOUNDARY"
        myRequestState.request.Method = "POST"

        ' Start the asynchronous 'BeginGetRequestStream' method call. 
        Dim r As IAsyncResult = CType(myWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(AddressOf ReadCallback, myRequestState), IAsyncResult)
        ' Pause the current thread until the async operation completes.
        allDone.WaitOne()

        ' Send the Post and get the response. 
        Dim myWebResponse As Net.WebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse()
        Dim streamResponse As IO.Stream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
        Dim streamRead As New IO.StreamReader(streamResponse)
        Dim readBuff(256) As [Char]
        Dim count As Integer = streamRead.Read(readBuff, 0, 256)

        While count > 0
            Dim outputData As New [String](readBuff, 0, count)
            Console.WriteLine(outputData)
            count = streamRead.Read(readBuff, 0, 256)
            StrResult += outputData 
        End While

        ' Close the Stream Object.
        streamResponse.Close()
        streamRead.Close()
        ' Release the HttpWebResponse Resource.
        myWebResponse.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Error in " & Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name.ToString & " **" & ex.Message, ex)
    End Try

    Return StrResult
End Function ' Upload
```

Again [here is the MSDN page for the WebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.method%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which has a code example too.

Hope this helps anyone who was stuck like I was. And any criticisms as to the implementation of the code are welcome. This just happen to do what I want, I can't say it is the most efficient implementation.